# how to print updated variable in log of unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class DetectCollision : MonoBehaviour
{
    private int score = 0;
    private int lives = 3;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
       
    void Start()
    {
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    
    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {

        if (other.tag == "food")
        {
            score++;
            Debug.Log(score);
            Destroy(gameObject);
            Destroy(other.gameObject);
        }
        if (other.tag == "Player")
        {
            score--;
            Debug.Log(score);
            if (score == 0)
            {
                Destroy(gameObject);
                Destroy(other.gameObject);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

I'm trying to reduce the life by one whenever the player hits any of the animals, and increase the score by one. If the food hits animals, but nothing else seems to be working dunno why. I want to update the score and life then print to log and if life hits 0 then delete the player. thanks

Comment: What game object is this script attached to?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your script is either attached to multiple game objects or a game object other than the player. You can fix this by making your variables static

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class DetectCollision : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static int score = 0;
    public static lives = 3;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
       
    void Start()
    {
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    
    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {

        if (other.tag == "food")
        {
            DetectCollision.score++;
            Debug.Log(DetectCollision.score);
            Destroy(gameObject);
            Destroy(other.gameObject);
        }
        if (other.tag == "Player")
        {
            DetectCollision.lives -=1;
            Debug.Log(DetectCollision.lives );
            if (DetectCollision.lives == 0)
            {
                Destroy(gameObject);
                Destroy(other.gameObject);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

It would be much better if you either created a new class called "Player" to attach these static variables to, or attach the collision code to only your player and have it check for objects the player hits without static variables.

Comment: add in "PlayerController" script, two new variables, and new two methods 

static int score = 0;
static int lives = 3;
    static public void hit()
    {
        lives--;
        if ( lives > 0 )
        {
            Debug.Log($"Lives = {lives}");
        } else
        {
            Debug.Log("Game Over!");
        }
    }

    static public void addScore()
    {
        score++;
        Debug.Log($"Score = {score}"); 
    }

------------------------------------------------------
add score:         PlayerController.addScore();
decrase lives:    PlayerController.hit();